# Trouble importing pandas_datareader

Tags: python, anaconda, datareader

I installed the package using the command line

```
conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader
```

But whenever I try to import in Jupyter notebook, I find an error

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-bc32bb8bec34> in <module>
----> 1 import pandas_datareader.data as web

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'
```

Comment: You might have installed in an virtual env, but jupyter might still be loading the kernel of your base virtual env. Try installing jupyter from within your env.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to do in the command line of anaconda (Anaconda CMD)

```
pip install pandas-datareader
```

Comment: I did. It continues to show the module not found error

Comment: Are you running your code with conda activated environment?

Comment: It worked! I had to seperetely install Jupyter within my conda environment and then run the notebook. Thanks for the help :)